# Construction of module on an Abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an Abelian group and let $\operatorname{End} M$ be the set of all endomorphims on $M$. Then $(\operatorname{End} M,+,\circ)$ forms a unitary ring. In this setting, if $R$ is a unitary ring and $\mu:R\to \operatorname{End} M$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\mu(1_R)=id_M$,then $M$ is an $R$-module under the action $R\times M\to M$ given by $(\lambda,m)\to\lambda m=[\mu(\lambda)](m)$.

In this process, I feel vagueness.

1. How much freedom do I have on constructing $\mu$? I mean, is there any explicit constraint on the structure of $\mu$ ? I only see the condition $\mu(1_R)=Id_M,$ and I cannot see any other constraint on $\mu(r)$ for some arbitrary $r\in R$, since $\mu(r*1_R)=\mu(r)\circ Id_M=\mu(r)$ (gives no information)
2. For this ring homomorphism $\mu$, what can I say about $\ker(\mu)$? I only can say this is an ideal of $R$, nothing more specific.
3. How can I use this discussion to show that $\mu$ is ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\operatorname{End}\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and$\operatorname{End} \mathbb{Q}$? I think I must show that $\ker (\mu)=0$ but as I don't see any clue on the structure of $\ker (\mu)$, it looks confusing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some hints:
What you've just done is to make $M$ into an $R$-module. You could equally look at $M$ as an abelian group (= $\Bbb Z$-module) with an action of the ring $R$, defined by $R \to Aut(M)$, **but** the main problem is, that not every image of $\mu$ is an automorphism. So, in fact, you could have $\varphi \in End(M) \setminus Aut(M)$ as an image of an element of $R$.

Besides that. In the construction of $\mu$ you have made actually *two* choices:

1. Via the condition $\mu(1_R) = id_M$ and
2. via the condition that $\mu$ is a *ring homomorphism*, that is $\mu(r*r') = \mu(r) \circ \mu(r')$

For your second question: The elements in the kernel of $\mu$ are those, who get mapped to the zero endomorphism. They form an ideal and measure how far it is from being injective.

For your third question: Take $A = R = \Bbb Z$. How could you define $\mu$ to be an isormophism? An endomorphism is an automorphism iff. it is injective. (Why?)

Hope that helped you a bit! :-)

Comment: +1. I would just add a small remark: the OP is using the ring homomorphism property for $\mu$ to prove in 2. that $\operatorname{ker}(\mu)$ is an ideal in $R$: this answers to the second question in 1. in the OP itself.

Comment: Thank you, @BIS HD. But I don't feel I got new insights... I know that I can use $\ker(\mu)$ to meausre how $\mu$ is far from being injective, but as long as I don't know what is 'in' the $\ker(\mu)$, I cannot use it usefully for applications. I mean, if there's some $r \neq 0_R, r \in \ker(\mu)$, $\ker(\mu)$ will be non-trivial ideal of $R$, but how can I know if such $r$ exists? I think that's what really matters but I'm still lost on that point...

Comment: To specify, 1) if there's no more specific condition on $M,R,\mu$, is "$\ker(\mu)$ is an ideal of $R$" is the best description I can make about $\ker(\mu)$? 2) I think that "for some $f\in End\mathbb{Z}$, $f=\mu[f(1)]$" may hold, but can I take the action, namely the product between integers, for granted, while I'm constructing an action (namely $\mu$) on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In your general setting, you can't really say more about the kernel of $\mu$ than I've done above. For $M = R = \Bbb Z$, maybe you should think about actually constructing $\mu$. What is a ring endomorphism of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: I can let $\mu(a) (a\in\mathbb{Z}$) be an endomorphism defined as $[\mu(a)](1)=a$, in other words, $[\mu(a)](b)=ab$. Then $ker(\mu)=\mu^{-1}(0)$, where $0$ is a trivial ring homomorphism. So $a\in \ker(\mu)$ iff "for all $b \in \mathbb{Z}, ab=0$", which is equivalent to $a=0$. So $\ker(\mu)=0$. So $\mu$ is injective. Am I right?

Comment: For surjectivity, for any $f\in End\mathbb{Z}$ we have $f(1)\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $\mu(f(1))=f$. But is it a direct result of "An endomorphism is an automorphism iff. it is injective"? Or is $\mathbb{Z}$ a special ring in which such proposition holds?

Comment: You are right, because $1$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z$ as an abelian group and any endomorphism is determined by the image of $1$. So letting $\Bbb Z$ act on $End \Bbb Z$ through multiplying by an element of $\Bbb Z$ is the only isomorphism that's possible.

Comment: Forget about this phrase. This is valid for fields or finite groups only. You're proof is correct though!